# A question regarding the order of an asymptotic estimate

Tags: calculus, asymptotics

Suppose that $m, n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that 
\begin{equation}
m \cdot \log m = n, 
\end{equation}
where the logarithm is in the natural base. How can we estimate the solution $m = m(n)$ asymptotically? Especially, can we find a function $f(n)$ such that
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{m}{f(n)} = 1.
\end{equation}
Thanks very much.

Comment: I think $n/\log n$ works, I'll check it shortly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f(n)=n/\log(n)$.  Then,
$$
\frac{m}{f(n)}=\frac{m}{n/\log(n)}=\frac{m\log(n)}{n}.
$$
Since $n=m\log m$, we can substitute to get 
$$
\frac{m}{f(n)}=\frac{m\log(n)}{m\log(m)}=\frac{\log(n)}{\log(m)}.
$$
Since $n=m\log m$, $\log(n)=\log(m)+\log(\log(m))$.  Therefore,
$$
\frac{m}{f(n)}=\frac{\log(n)}{\log(m)}=\frac{\log(m)+\log(\log(m))}{\log(m)}=1+\frac{\log(\log(m))}{\log(m)}.
$$
As $m$ grows, the second term vanishes.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help!